# Cannot find .properties file in Classpath

Tags: java, tomcat, properties, classpath, solaris

i am having trouble using a third party .jar in my JSP web application.
This third party .jar is using a .properties file which should be located in the classpath.

This is a code snippet used for locating the file (extracted from the .jar):

```
...
for (String classpath : new String[]{ "sun.boot.class.path", "java.class.path", "java.ext.dirs" })
            for (String path : System.getProperty(classpath).split(System.getProperty("path.separator")))
                listSearchPaths.add(new File(path));
...
```

From what I understand, the application is looking in three different system properties:

- sun.boot.class.path
- java.class.path
- java.ext.dir

After building, the required .properties file is located in the same folder as the third party .jar

Project.war/WEB-INF/lib/file.properties 
Project.war/WEB-INF/lib/thirdparty.jar

---

Here is the problem:

I am trying to run this .war on a tomcat6 server on Solaris. The server is starting successfully, but at runtime, when using the thirdparty functionality, the application cannot find the .properties file in classpath.

I tried several things like: 
 - setting .properties in tomcat common/shared loader 
 - setting .properties in classpath tag in build.xml during compilation

I also printed out the current classpath during runtime, which is only resulting in  "/usr/apache/tomcat6/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/bin/bootstrap.jar"

I know that there is a difference between tomcat classpath and java classpath but I cannot get the hang of it right now.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried putting the .properties file in WEB-INF/classes instead of WEB-INF/lib? That should be the correct classpath.

Comment: No, but I solved it by now using this approach:

- copied .properties file to tomcat folder 
- created setenv.sh script to alter environment variables
- added .properties file to CLASSPATH variable

Comment: That's a not very portable and not very standard-like solution. Perhaps you should try standards first before asking yourself why it is no longer working when switching to another servlet container in two years...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. Will try your solution then.

Comment: Let me know if it works, I will add it as answer then.